# DateTime.TryParseExact() with Format array always returns false

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, parsing

After digging through SO, I'm still not seeing anything about what is happening here.

```
 string[] Formats = new string[] { "dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss:fff", "YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff" };
                    DateTime t = new DateTime();

                    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
                        dataItem.Trim(), 
                        Formats ,                         
                        System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
                        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
                        out t)
                        == false)
                        return false;
                        else
                        return DoOtherStuff(dataItem);
```

The incoming data, "`dataItem`", is a `string`.   The incoming text looks like:

02 Jan 2016 13:15:49:447

What am I missing?  Why does this always return `false', regardless of the date?  I've tried converting the string to uppercase but that changed nothing.

Comment: Did you try running your code without the array, looking at whether either of those formats work?  You also might consider formatting your code to be readable

Comment: Not solving your problem but these days you can use `out var t` to do the variable declaration inline instead of declaring `DateTime t = new DateTime()` before the call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `YYYY` is capitalized. The correct year symbol you are looking for is `yyyy`.

`string[] Formats = new string[] { "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:fff" };` should work.

Comment: This could've been checked yourself by trying all the parts. Check if `"02"` is parsed by '"dd"` etc. When you try to parse `"2016"` with the format `"YYYY"` you would've seen that parsing fails.

Comment: Yes, this is a great approach; I also recommend keeping the custom datetime format spec open while writing formats: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings